# Nested search in MongoDB

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

In my model schema which called `Quotations` I have a field called `customer` which in type of `ObjectId` and I have defined `ref` also,

```
customer: {
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: "Customer",
  },
```

And I tried a search function to get a quotation by customer's name like this,

```
const quotations = await Quotation.find({
      "customer.firstName": keyword,
})
```

I can't figure out why this is not working. Can somebody point out me the error. Thanks

Comment: Referenced fields don't work like that. All `customer` has is an `ObjectId` so you can't search in it. You need to use `populate` to replace the `ObjectId` with the actual customer document. But this is done *after* a query so you cannot filter parent documents based on a query condition of a child document. There are a couple of approaches to doing this either programmatically by filtering or using an aggregation which is more efficient.

Comment: Can you provide me a solution please. Thanks for replying

Comment: Yes of course. I will add an aggregation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an aggregation. I have assumed you have a `quotations` collection and a `customers` collection.

1. `$lookup` the `customers` collection and match each `Quotation.customer` value with the `Customer._id` value.
2. `$match` the `customer.firstName` your `keyword`.
3. `$unwind` the new `customer` fields because `$lookup` always returns an array.

```js
const quotations = await Quotation.aggregate([
  {
    $lookup: {
      "from": "customers",
      "localField": "customer",
      "foreignField": "_id",
      "as": "customer"
    }
  },
  {
    $match: {
      "customer.firstName": keyword
    }
  },
  {
    $unwind: "$customer"
  }
])
```

See [HERE](https://mongoplayground.net/p/cqKebAYITlj) for a working example.

**Edit**:

For efficiency, in the above example I have moved the `$match` stage before the `$unwind` because `$unwind` can be expensive if you have a lot of results so by using `$match` first you are reducing the number to `$unwind` in the last stage.

Another alternative is to search the `customers` collection first. Use the returned results to construct an array of `ObjectId`s and pass these to a `find` with `$in` to look for matches on `customer` like so:

```js
const customers = await Customer.find({firstName: keyword});
const ids = customers.map((c) => c._id);
const quotations = await Quotation.find({
    customer: {
        $in: ids
    }
}).populate('customer');
```

Lastly the least efficient is to search the `quotations` collection and `populate` with `customers`. From the returned results you can filter the array for matches on `customer.firstName` like so:

```js
const docs = await Quotation.find({}).populate('customer');
const quotations = docs.filter((d) => d.customer?.firstName === keyword);
```

Comment: Thankyou so much. Is this the best way to go?

Comment: It depends on what your metric for measuring best means. You can use populate then once you have all documents filter them with JavaScript or you can search the Customer collection first to get an `id` then use that to find the Quotations but that means two db hits. I can add a few different approaches once I get access to a computer later.